# Why are orphaned child processes not adopted by PID 1 in Linux, like it is claimed in a book I read?

Tags: c, process, operating-system, systemd

I was reading "The Linux Programming Interface" book and got to this sentence (at the end of chapter 6.2):

> If a child process becomes orphaned because its “birth” parent terminates, then the child is adopted by the *init* process, and subsequent calls to *getppid()* in the child return 1.

So I wrote some code to see this.  Here is the code:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("starting...\n");

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        printf("Child PID: %d\n",getpid());
        printf("Child PPID: %d\n",getppid());
        printf("sleeping till the parent die:(\n");
        sleep(5);
        printf("Child new PPID: %d\n",getppid());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Parent PID: %d\n",getpid());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After running the code, I've got this output:

```text
starting...
Parent PID: 16577
Child PID: 16578
Child PPID: 16577
sleeping till the parent die:(

Child new PPID: 2754
```

Not only is `getppid()` not returning 1, it looks like PID 1 is not even the `init` process, but instead a `systemd` process.  And there are multiple of them: when I ran `pgrep systemd`, it output, among others, 1 and 2754.

Now I'm confused and these are my questions:

- Where is the `init` process?
- Why are there multiple `systemd` processes?

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. can you help me find an updated source for Linux programming?

Comment: Presumably PID 2754 is your [user session manager (`systemd --user`)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/user@.service.html). The user session manager was made reaper of orphaned processes in 2012: <https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2012-July/005991.html>. You can check by running `systemctl status "user@$UID"`.

Comment: @user3840170 Thank you. your comment should be the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it looks like PID 1 is not even the init process, but instead a systemd process

The systemd process *is* the init process. It is not the same software as traditional init, but it still does all the functions that init would normally do (and a bit more; it's not just a straight-up reimplementation of init).

Although the "SysV init" has historically been the most popular init for Linux, it has never been the only one – it's a distro choice, so you also had init-ng, s6, Upstart, systemd, etc.

> And there are multiple of them: when I ran pgrep systemd, it output, among others, 1 and 2754.

Service management is not uniquely restricted to init/pid1 – though pid1 has somewhat of an advantage due to being the default parent – but it is fairly common to have a "user-level" service manager that does roughly the same thing. For example, when you log in to GNOME, the initial process there is gnome-session – which is just another kind of service manager, doing nothing but starting overseeing various other GNOME components.

So, naturally, systemd supports a mode where it can run as an ordinary non-pid1 process and manage services for one specific user (via `systemctl --user`). These days a large chunk of your GUI environment components gets started this way.

(You didn't really see it with SysV-style init because its service management features were... lacking, with practically everything done via shell tools *outside* init proper. But both Upstart and systemd handle services directly within pid1.)

Therefore,

> Not only is getppid() not returning 1

As noted in the comments, Linux now provides an API for standalone service managers to become the new default parent (reaper) for their child processes. Systemd in its "per-user" mode uses this in order to more easily deal with services that try to "daemonize" (and therefore become orphaned).